# Space Delimiter Arrays Shell Script

Tags: arrays, shell, delimiter

Array is taking "space" as default delimiter:

```
str="HI I GOT;IT"

arr2=$(echo $str | tr ";" " ")
for x in $arr2
do
echo " $x"
done
```

Output:

HI

I

GOT

IT

I want the output to be:

HI I GOT

IT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said which shell this is, but it looks like `bash`, so I'll go ith that.  This is a job for `IFS`, which determines how `bash` splits words. Here we set it to `;` for a single command, to split up your string.

You also need to iterate over the array properly (using quotes and `[@]`) so that it's not split again by bash at this point.

```
str="HI I GOT;IT"
IFS=\; arr=($str)
for x in "${arr[@]}"
do
    echo "$x"
done
```